# databricks reference variable in run command

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

In databricks I'm passing in a variable from ADF which works fine when I print it:

[image]

But how do I reference it in a %run statement later on?  It's done this way because the main.py script is stored in DBFS, but if there's a better way of running the script please let me know.

[image]

I know it works if I replace the job_path variable to the actual value:
`%run /dbfs/FileStore/main.py --job_path process_source_product_category.py`

So I had assume this would be the same?
`%run /dbfs/FileStore/main.py --job_path job_path`

Not sure if dynamic python is the way forward but I'm open to suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out, it was just missing a dollar sign in front of the variable:

```
spark.read.text("/FileStore/main.py")

%run /dbfs/FileStore/main.py --job_path $job_path
```